# Nodejitsu app stops immediately after starting

Tags: node.js, express, nodejitsu

I'm quite new to node.js, so bear with me. I've set up a basic Portfolio site using node, express, and some bootstrap, and everything runs fine locally ([on github](https://github.com/deanlai/Builtbysean)). When I deploy and/or start my app on nodejitsu I get this message:

```
info:    Updating app Portfolio
info:    Activating snapshot 0.0.1-4 for Portfolio
info:    Starting app Portfolio
info:    App Portfolio is now started
info:    http://builtbysean.jit.su on Port 80
info:    Nodejitsu ok
```

Seems okay? Well upon visiting the url I am greeted by a Nodejitsu 400 error "builtbysean.jit.su is currently stopped."
Immediately running `$ jitsu apps view` reveals that my app is indeed stopped (see active: false, running: false near the bottom)

```
info:    Viewing app Portfolio
data:    {
data:        dependencies: { express: '3.3.4', jade: '0.33.0' },
data:        name: 'Portfolio',
data:        domains: [],
data:        config: {},
data:        scripts: { start: 'node app.js' },
data:        user: 'deanlai',
data:        subdomain: 'builtbysean',
data:        drones: 0,
data:        maxDrones: 1,
data:        engines: { node: '0.8.x', npm: '1.3.2' },
data:        snapshots: [
data:            { id: '0.0.1', created: '07/18 22:52:26 PDT' },
data:            { id: '0.0.1-1', created: '07/19 10:28:24 PDT' },
data:            { id: '0.0.1-2', created: '07/19 18:23:52 PDT' },
data:            { id: '0.0.1-3', created: '07/19 18:33:22 PDT' },
data:            { id: '0.0.1-4', created: '07/19 19:44:14 PDT' }
data:        ],
data:        ctime: '07/18 22:51:06 PDT',
data:        subscriptionId: 3627690,
data:        version: '0.0.1-4',
data:        active: {
data:            id: '0.0.1-4',
data:            md5: '7a484e5758bdaf1c89d01a98d53868a4',
data:            filename: 'deanlai-Portfolio-0.0.1-4.tgz',
data:            ctime: '07/19 19:44:14 PDT',
data:            active: false,
data:            running: false
data:        },
data:        databases: {},
data:        mtime: '07/19 19:48:48 PDT',
data:        env: { SUBDOMAIN: 'builtbysean', NODE_ENV: 'production' }
data:    }
```

Any idea what's going on? I'm not getting any errors thrown on my end so it's difficult to diagnose. I also made the simple hello app in nodejitsu's starting guide and it deployed, started, and stayed running without issue, so it would seem there is something "wrong" with my app that is causing nodejitsu to stop running the app (again, there are no problems running it locally).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app may be error looping. I had experienced same case before. Check your logs and see if you will get a clue

jitsu logs

Otherwise, contact their support (https://www.nodejitsu.com/support/)

You may also go to their IRC webchat - webchat.jit.su

Comment: I checked the logs but there don't seem to be any. Should the apps create logs automatically or is there something I have to turn on (in package.json perhaps)? Note, the functional hello test app also has no logs.

Comment: The logs basically contains texts written on the console. If your app is throwing an error, it should show on the logs. And yes it should be turned on by default.

Comment: If you are not getting logs, I'm not sure what else could be causing it. Your best bet is contact Nodejitsu support.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did end up contacting nodejitsu support but it being the weekend didn't get much response. So, I moved all the static files and views to a brand new express skeleton with minimized dependencies and now it works fine. Still no clue what was happening before.